# How to change textbox style in css

Tags: jquery, css

[image]

> It's possible to change default style in text area in html5.
>   I need change to text area style using css. How change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
::-webkit-resizer {
    background: url(http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.png);    
    background-size:100%;    
}
::-moz-resizer {
    background: url(http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.png);    
    background-size:100%;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this, write a class and call the class in to your text area

```css
.tex_area {
 background-color:#99FFCC;
 width: 300px;
 height: 100px;
 font: normal 14px verdana;
 line-height: 25px;
 padding: 2px 10px;
 border: solid 1px #ddd;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="tex_area"></textarea>
```

Comment: Haha. I assume you don't see the arrow he created.